# Synonym request: [paging] to [pagination]

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

While searching today I found 2 similar tags that could get synonymized.

These tags are [paging](/questions/tagged/paging) and [pagination](/questions/tagged/pagination).

Comment: maybe we need to ban the "paging" tag on new questions and force people to use takgs like memory-paging etc

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I don't think they are synonyms:

**Paging** doesn't necessarily mean pagination in computing:

1. From the [Wikipedia article on Paging](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paging)

   > In computer operating systems, paging is one of the memory-management
   >   schemes by which a computer can store and retrieve data from secondary
   >   storage for use in main memory.
2. Paging can refer to the act of reading data tables page by page (credit to [@Ian Ringrose](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/132223/ian-ringrose))
3. Paging can refer to the act of sending data to a pager (credit to @Al Everett)

...where as **pagination** is to divide up copy into pages, as one might do when designing a UI.