# Confusion about the paging and pagination tags

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

The [paging](/questions/tagged/paging) and [pagination](/questions/tagged/pagination) tags are confusing. I understand that both are well-defined as explained here:

https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/118522/153951

But most users who don't read tag descriptions very often are oblivious of this difference. I suggest:

- Creating a new tag [memory-paging](/questions/tagged/memory-paging) (or similar, something starting with paging-xxx)
- Migrating all questions related to memory paging from [paging](/questions/tagged/paging) to [memory-paging](/questions/tagged/memory-paging)
- Migrating all questions related to pagination from [paging](/questions/tagged/paging) to [pagination](/questions/tagged/pagination)
- Migrating further questions from [custompaging](/questions/tagged/custompaging) to [pagination](/questions/tagged/pagination) (while we're at it...)
- Deleting [paging](/questions/tagged/paging)

Comment: Why do you guys always wait until there are a thousand questions under a bad tag before pointing out that there's a problem? :/

Comment: ;-) @RobertHarvey: Because before, there *is* no problem. But today, I have retagged about 10 questions from [tag:paging] to [tag:pagination]. So a little less work